# Molecular psychology/psychiatry literature/articles

Tags: literature

I am new biology student which is on molecular biology subject on university. I would like to know something about genetic related to neurobiology, and certainly molecular psychiatry/psychology, perhaps evolution psychology. But i dont know where to start.

Can anybody give me type to literature/articles for beginners?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the neurobiology I'd recommend to read: [Mapping the Mind](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/947061.Mapping_the_Mind) and [The Quest for Conscioussness](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/125257.The_Quest_for_Consciousness) , but these are kind of long books.

For shorter articles as (merely) an introduction, I'd recommend:

Manoli, D. S., Meissner, G. W., & Baker, B. S. (2006). Blueprints for behavior: genetic specification of neural circuitry for innate behaviors. Trends in Neurosciences, 29(8), 444–451. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tins.2006.06.006

Good philosphical and historical viewpoint can also be found here:

Marler, P. (2004). Innateness and the instinct to learn. Anais Da Academia Brasileira de Ciencias, 76(2), 189–200. https://doi.org/10.1590/S0001-37652004000200002

For something more practical: [The Little Black Book of Neuropsychology.](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10330039-the-little-black-book-of-neuropsychology)

Looking forward to suggestions by others :)